# Why when user click "Send" dont appears any error but also the page is not refreshed?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page for a user to send notifications.

The user needs to fill some form fields and then click send.

The issue is that when the user click "Send" nothing happens, dont appears any error, the page is not refreshed. Do you know what can be the issue?

The form action is like below:

```
    <form method="post" class="clearfix" 
    action="{{route('notifications.send', 
   ['conference_id' => $conference->id])}}" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        ...

        <input type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn" 
        value="Send"/>
    </form>
```

Then I have the route:

```
   Route::post('conference/notify/{id}/send', 
   [ 'uses' => 'NotificationController@send', 'as'=>'notifications.send']);
```

And in the NotificationController:

```
public function send(Request $request, $id){


        dd($request->all());
        ....
}
```

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools console to see if you have any errors. That's most likely the reason why your form is not getting submitted. I'm assuming you don't have any JS event handlers for the form `submit` event that can explicitly prevent it from being submitted.

Comment: It appears an error "An invalid form control with name='participant_email' is not focusable.".